# How to fetch issues for a date range

Tags: redmine

Using the REST API is it possible to returns all issues created after a given date(for eg:2013-03-13)

I tried `GET /issues.json?created_on>2013-03-13`. But the result displays all the issues. Is it possible to get Issue after a given date.

Is it also possible to get issue after a given date with time for eg:
`GET /issues.json?created_on>2013-03-13 11:45:36 +0530`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fast solution**

```
GET /issues.json?set_filter=1&f[]=created_on&op[created_on]=%3E%3D&v[created_on][]=2013-04-23
```

for example

```
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/issues.json?set_filter=1&f[]=created_on&op[created_on]=%3E%3D&v[created_on][]=2013-04-23
```

**How to find the matching filter**

Browse the issues list with your favorite browser and set some filters in the UI (there is a `Add filter` select box right above the issue listing). Then click `apply` and wait until the page loaded. Now inspect the current URL. In the URL replace `[...]/issues?[...]` with `[...]/issues.json?[...]`, and you have your json output.

Unfortunately I can't find a filter for times. But it should be easy to develop a redmine plugin (or patch for the redmine core) to implement such a filter.

**Further investigation**

The `Issues#index` controller action actually builds a Query object from your parameters. You can read about creating that query in the [queries_helper.rb#L184](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/helpers/queries_helper.rb#L184)